# wal-g backup-push tries to use wrong database

Tags: postgresql, wal, patroni

When trying to use wal-g with Patroni, I've got the following configuration as the Postgres section of patroni.yml:

```
postgresql:
  use_pg_rewind: true
  use_slots: true
  parameters:
    wal_level: logical
    hot_standby: "on"
    wal_keep_segments: 8
    max_wal_senders: 8
    max_replication_slots: 8
    checkpoint_timeout: 30
    archive_mode: "on"
    archive_command: PGUSER=dba PGPASSWORD=xx WALG_FILE_PREFIX=file://localhost/backup-disk/ wal-g wal-push "%p"
  recovery_conf:
    restore_command: PGUSER=dba PGPASSWORD=xx WALG_FILE_PREFIX=file://localhost/backup-disk/ wal-g wal-fetch "%f" "%p"
```

However if I then try to create a backup using `PGHOST=/var/run/postgresql PGUSER=dba PGPASSWORD=xx envdir /data/conf/wal-e.env wal-g backup-push /data/postgresql/current`, it tries to connect to the `dba` database which doesn't exist:

```
INFO:  Doing full backup.
ERROR: Connect: postgres connection failed: FATAL: database "dba" does not exist (SQLSTATE 3D000)
```

From the wal-g docs and searching, it's not obvious why this is not the case, so in an attempt to make things more discoverable I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be quite simple once I checked out the [WAL-G source code](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g) and found that examples of their environment config for their tests contained the following setting:

```
PGDATABASE=postgres
```

So to have a backup apparently work, I now have the following:

```
PGDATABASE=postgres PGHOST=/var/run/postgresql PGUSER=dba PGPASSWORD=xx WALG_FILE_PREFIX=file://localhost/backup-disk/ wal-g backup-push /data/postgresql/current
```

This creates the expected files in `/backup-disk/`, so now *all* I need to do is sort out scheduling some backups of the correct database.

Comment: Do you know if setting PGDATABASE=postgres will backup only the postgres database, or if it'll backup the entire cluster, i.e. all the databases?